# Enabling HAV in Guest OS of VMware Workstation

Tags: vmware-workstation, virtualization

I'm using VMware Workstation and my Host OS is Windows 7 Home Premium.

I've installed Win 7 Ultimate as a guest os, it's working perfectly.
Both are 64 bit.

I need to convert my old XP into a virtual machine (p2v). I've used disk2vhd to create the virtual hard drive, but VMware couldn't use that file. After some more researches I've read that I should first use Virtual PC to create the virtual machine and only then convert it with VMware workstation.

I know it's really weird to use virtualization software over already virtualized os but it's only for one time use and that's the only way I could use Virtual PC.

When I'm trying to use the Virtual PC I'm receiving the following message:
`Windows Virtual PC cannot start because this computer does not support hardware-assisted virtualization.`

**How can I enable HAV in the guest os?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VMware have a free product called [VMware Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/) for doing p2v it is probably better to use that to convert you XP machine and run it natively.

There is also a product called winimage which [these instructions](http://www.sertec.ca/howtos/Howto-Convert-VHD-to-VMDK-Partition-types.html) suggest will convert the vhd that you have to VMware vmdk format.